# Does Oracle SQL support output parameters in system functions?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL, do any of the system functions (listed on http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions001.htm) support output parameters, or do they only return a value?

I know that in Oracle PL/SQL, a function can return values and can contain output parameters, but do any SQL system functions themselves have output parameters?

Comment: Functions, by definition, do not support output parameters. If you look at the documentation of the functions referenced in the cited source, you will see that the spec of all of them does NOT include an "output parameter" - as opposed to a return value.  I don't even see anything in the PL/SQL reference to indicate that a PL/SQL function can do any different.  And look at the doc on CREATE FUNCTION.  Same story.

Comment: To elaborate Ed's answer: In PL/SQL you can do some processing and output values through out parameters, but that kind of program is called a procedure, not a function. This kind of terminology may be used somewhat differently in other languages, but this is the Oracle usage.

Comment: @EdStevens Functions **do** support out parameters: `CREATE FUNCTION test_out(
  value OUT NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  value := 1;
  RETURN 2;
END;
/` then you can do `DECLARE
  a NUMBER;
  b NUMBER;
BEGIN
  a := test_out( b );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( a || ', ' || b );
END;
/`

Comment: @mathguy No, you can get out parameters on functions as well as procedures.

Comment: @EdStevens The syntax for `CREATE FUNCTION` includes out parameters in the [parameter declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/formal_parameter.htm#CJAJDGCC) section.

Comment: I stand corrected.  But note this, from the 11.2 PL/SQL Language Reference:  Note:
Avoid using OUT and IN OUT for function parameters. The purpose of a function is to take zero or more parameters and return a single value. Functions must be free from side effects, which change the values of variables not local to the subprogram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Functions with out parameters can only be used in PL/SQL.

As an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_out(
  value OUT NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  value := 1;
  RETURN 2;
END;
/
```

You can run this in PL/SQL:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  a NUMBER;
  b NUMBER;
BEGIN
  a := test_out( b );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( a || ', ' || b );
END;
/
```

Outputs `2, 1`

However, trying to do the same thing in SQL (creating a bind variable via Oracle's SQL Developer):

```
VARIABLE a NUMBER;

SELECT test_out( :a ) FROM DUAL;

PRINT a;
```

Gives you the exception:

```
SQL Error: ORA-06572: Function TEST_OUT has out arguments
06572. 00000 -  "Function %s has out arguments"
*Cause:    A SQL statement references either a packaged, or a stand-alone,
           PL/SQL function that contains an OUT parameter in its argument
           list. PL/SQL functions referenced by SQL statements must not
           contain the OUT parameter.
*Action:   Recreate the PL/SQL function without the OUT parameter in the
           argument list.
```